# Passing location information from uibutton to a map view page and start navigating

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSQ0l.png)

```html
    
    var location: [Location] = [
    
    Location(title: "LaFarge Hall", cllocation: CLLocation(latitude: 39.992853, longitude: -75.239888), regionRadius: 300.0, location: "Cardinal Ave", type: "Dorm Hall", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( 39.992853, -75.239888))
    ]
    
    @IBAction func tapDidNavi(sender: UIButton){
        
        
    }
```

I have a list of buttons which are drop - off locations places that users can choose from. When the user clicks the button, the button will move to the map view page and draw google polyliner path from the current location to the location that they select. Drop -off location buttons are in the array that includes the location coordinates, and I want to pass the location coordinates and start a map view that draws the path from the current location to the coordinates.

Comment: Can you provide the source code of where these locations can be selected in your app?

Comment: I just included in the source code.

Comment: @A.Welch i also included a link to a screenshot of my storyboard. There's a list of buttons, and I want to put these buttons in array which includes there location coordinates, and when the user clicks on the buttons; it would direct them to the map view page, and draw a path from the current location to the drop off location.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to use a UITableView here instead of a list of buttons. But if you need to use a list of buttons this should work:

Just create a subclass of UIButton and add a location property to its initializer.

```
class LocationButton: UIButton {

public var location : Location

init(location: Location, frame: CGRect) {

    self.location = location

    super.init(frame: frame)

    setProperties()
}

///needed for interface builder 
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

private func setProperties() {
    //Set properties of button here...
    setTitle("Button Title", for: .normal)
   }
}
```

Creating a 'LocationButton' will look similar to this:

```
let locationButton = LocationButton(location: Location(title: "LaFarge Hall", location: CLLocation(), frame: CGRect())
```

Make sure to also add a target to each button in the array:

```
locationButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapDidNavi(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Update your tapDidNavi() function to accept a LocationButton type. Then you will be able to grab the location off any button pressed and pass it to the next viewController like so:

```
@IBAction func tapDidNavi(sender: LocationButton) {
    let nextViewController = SomeViewController() //This viewController must have a 'public var Location' inside of it.
    nextViewController.location = sender.location //The location object you set on the button

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: how I am able to have the view controller which is the map view controller grab the location? In my map view controller I just have the properties var locationManager = CLocationManager()

Comment: when i type nextViewContrroller.location = sender.location it doesnt work

Comment: Add this property to your mapViewController:  var location: Location!

Comment: And switch “nextViewController” with the name of your mapViewController